# Respuesta detallada acerca de ser y estar

Tags: discusión

El tema de *ser* vs *estar* es algo que causa mucha frustración y preguntas a casi todos los que aprenden español.

Aquí en este Stack tenemos **128** preguntas sobre este tema y casi todos son de casos específicos, pero no tenemos una pregunta básica como "Reglas del uso de ser y estar" y una respuesta dando todas las reglas y usos. ¿O sería demasiado grande, quizás?

---

[image: ser vs estar]

---

¿Podríamos escribir algo muy detallado acerca de *ser* y *estar* para las personas con preguntas? Además, tal vez podríamos cerrar algunas preguntas y desviarlas a este articulo detallado.

Yo quizás haría esto, pero no soy un experto en el idioma de español. Lo apreciaría mucho si otro lo hiciera.

Answer (score 1):

Sí estoy de acuerdo con la proposición. Excepto por algunos puntos:

- No pienso que sea una buena idea de redirigir todas las preguntas que estén relacionadas con el tema hacia la nueva pregunta. Hay muchas preguntas que pueden ser específicas y tener una duda legítima que no sea resuelta en otra parte.
- Cerrar las preguntas tampoco me parece una buena idea, hay muchas preguntas sobre el tema que son buenas preguntas y que como dicho anteriormente no serían necesariamente resueltas por una referencia general. ***Algunas*** preguntas eventualmente pero dudo que sean muchas. Seguramente las más basicas.

Solamente una opinión.

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta finalmente se ha formulado en el sitio principal:

[What are the differences between "ser" and "estar"? When to use each? // ¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre "ser" y "estar"? ¿Cuándo se usa cada uno?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19836/12637)

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que una respuesta para la pregunta genérica es algo que se vería en una enciclopedia.  Aquí hay una presentación mas o menos básica.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbo_copulativo

Claro que, para un principiante en español, vale más darle una explicación en su propio idioma.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo que se puede encontrarlo en una enciclopedia, pero la meta de este sitio es proveer un lugar donde se puede encontrar información así, no? O quizás tengo una idea equivocada?

Comment: No estoy seguro.  Puede ser que tengas razón.  Pero hay varios participantes en otras areas que opinan que un sitio de respuestas detalladas de la pregunta mas general contaminan la meta de un sitio Q&A.

Comment: Bueno. Sería interesante leer lo que piensan los demás.