# Necesitamos una pregunta canónica sobre ser/estar

Tags: discusión, duplicados-exactos, pregunta-específica, preguntas-canónicas

Mirando [What is the difference between “el examen fue largo” and “el examen estuvo largo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17983/1674) pensé inmediatamente que esto debe estar ya respuesto en algún momento del pasado.

Tiré del hilo buscando preguntas que hablen de "ser" y de "estar" y [`ser estar is:q`](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=ser%20estar%20is%3Aq) me devuelve nada menos que 43 resultados. ¡Esto es mucho!

Para evitar que cada nueva pregunta contenga material repetido, o cuanto menos para evitar la dispersión de conocimiento, sugiero que busquemos los casos más generales para luego identificar qué preguntas / respuestas lo cubren mejor, convirtiéndolas en las canónicas para marcar como duplicadas.

¿Qué os parece? ¿Qué tipos básicos recomendáis? ¿Cuáles de las preguntas / respuestas os parecen especialmente meritorias?

---

Secciones de *ser/estar* que veo ya representadas en el sitio:

- estar hecho de:
  [Why should we use "estar" over "ser" for being old or fat?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/236/why-should-we-use-estar-over-ser-for-being-old-or-fat)
- estar de estado: [¿Por qué decimos "esta bolsa 'está' rota" y no 'es'?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8609/por-qu%C3%A9-decimos-esta-bolsa-est%C3%A1-rota-y-no-es)
- ser feliz: [Translation of the phrase "I'm happy."](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15549/translation-of-the-phrase-im-happy)
- ser/estar passive voice: [Ser and Estar differences in passive voice?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5798/ser-and-estar-differences-in-passive-voice)
- ser estar for location: ['Ser' and 'estar' for location / Uso de "ser" y "estar" para ubicación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1790/ser-and-estar-for-location)

Comment: ¿Has puesto "respuesto" adrede? :-)

Comment: La reciente pregunta sobre la diferencia entre "a" y "ha" podría ser un buen ejemplo de pregunta canónica, porque es un tema recurrente que nos suele dar problemas hasta a los propios hispanohablantes, y lo mejor es que la respuesta tampoco tiene por qué ser muy larga.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> La pregunta se ha formulado en el sitio principal aquí: [What are the differences between "ser" and "estar"? When to use each? // ¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre "ser" y "estar"? ¿Cuándo se usa cada uno?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19836/12637)

---

Sí, se nos acumulan las preguntas acerca de los verbos "ser" y "estar". Yo crearía una pregunta en modo *community wiki* que fuese algo genérico, tal vez simplemente:

> ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los verbos "ser" y "estar"?

En el enunciado de la pregunta se pueden poner referencias, como dices, a las preguntas con más votos hasta ahora acerca del tema. En la respuesta, también en modo *community wiki*, se pueden enlazar todos los textos que encontremos que hablen acerca de las diferencias, comenzando por la Nueva Gramática Española y acabando donde se tercie. También se pueden hacer menciones a las respuestas más votadas que ya haya habido en este sitio.

Importante que tanto la pregunta como las respuestas estén en español e inglés, y que haya enlaces a sitios en diferentes idiomas que hablen acerca del tema ([ejemplo de la Wikipedia en inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_copula#Spanish)).

Con un poco de esfuerzo entre todos creo que podríamos crear la pregunta definitiva. Dicha pregunta se podría anunciar de alguna forma fija en la columna derecha del sitio (al estilo de las preguntas *featured* de meta), y si aparece alguna pregunta nueva que trate el mismo tema se le redirige allí para que, si es algo nuevo que aún no esté respondido o algún detalle particular, se pueda añadir a la respuesta.

Por otro lado, y ahora que lo pienso, dado el caso de que necesitamos más preguntas al día en el sitio para poder salir de la beta, ¿realmente queremos cortar un flujo tan numeroso de preguntas como el que provoca la confusión entre "ser" y "estar"?

Comment: ¡Gracias por responder! (Pensaba que estaba solo en Meta :D) Me gusta la manera de abordarlo mediante una pregunta creada a tal efecto, en lugar de elegir una de las ya existentes. La podemos ir construyendo poco a poco en base a lo que vemos en otras de las preguntas del tema. Y si vemos que se alarga demasiado, publicamos distintas respuestas, una para cada casuística.

Comment: En cuanto al efecto pernicioso de reducir el flujo de preguntas, no creo que deba ser un problema principal. Considero más beneficioso tener una buena base de preguntas/respuestas buenas, útiles, para que la gente coja este sitio como una buena referencia. Luego, seguro que surgen preguntas interesantes de otros temas (tú mismo eres un buen ejemplo de ello, siempre se te ocurren nuevas cuestiones a preguntar que acaban mejorando el sitio). Creo que ahora mismo el problema principal es el de la cantidad de gente que pulula por aquí.

Comment: @fedorqui debo reconocer que le echo poca cuenta al meta, sólo accedo cuando veo algún enlace desde la página principal del sitio estándar. Si crees que la calidad es mejor cantidad (cosa muy loable), por mí no hay problema. Vamos a ver si alguien más opina al respecto y ya decidimos qué hacer en unos días, demos de plazo hasta el viernes (por ejemplo) antes de crear la pregunta definitiva o lo que sea menester.

Comment: Me parece bien. Tal y como sugeriste en [¡Estamos de enhorabuena! Estado efervescente del sitio y cómo seguir creciendo](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2491), podemos relajar un poco la clausura por duplicados y crear esta pregunta no tiene porqué implicar que las otras 43 preguntas sean automáticamente cerradas. Miremos después cada caso y solo cerremos los que realmente lo requiran.

Comment: @fedorqui no sé yo, yo creo que si hasta ahora no hemos cerrado ninguna pregunta sobre "ser" y "estar" por duplicada, menos aun debemos hacerlo a causa de una pregunta que se haya publicado **después** de la que debería haberse cerrado. Eso sí, las nuevas preguntas relacionadas que se hagan tras la publicación de ésta sí se deberán marcar como duplicadas.

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea. Bear in mind that people learning Spanish start by being told many half truths of which one is ser=permanent, estar=temporary. Then they move to learning a whole set of apparent exceptions about things like profession, time, and so on. My impression is that native speakers learn all this so early in life with their mother's milk that they find it hard to see what the rules are. There is a final third stage of learning where very subtle distinctions can be made. I am not sure how deep the canonical answer needs to be or can be.

Comment: Los duplicados pueden ser anteriores a los que se convierten en canónicos. Esto se hace en todo [se] y su lógica es clara: lo importante es concentrar el conocimiento y, para ello, se elige la pregunta que mejor lo estructura. De Community Manager de [se] en [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/209901): _If the new question is a better question or has better answers, then vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one_.

Comment: @fedorqui entiendo tu razonamiento, pero lo entendería aún más si las preguntas antiguas no se cerraran por duplicadas sino por **obsoletas**. Así quedaría más claro que hay una nueva respuesta más actualizada y con más información.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo no comparto el término obsoleto: alguien tuvo una duda y se le resolvió. De ser así, dar a "aceptar" convertiría todas las preguntas en obsoletas porque ya están contestadas y la duda ya no existe en la mente de quien la preguntó. Sea como fuere, el término es lo de menos. Lo bueno de marcarlas como duplicadas es que a los usuarios no registrados se los redirige a la página de la promovida como principal, permitiendo que se erija como el punto importante de conocimiento sobre el tema. Ah, también se puede hace [merge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158067/209901) en algún caso.

Comment: @fedorqui sea como fuere, marcar las preguntas antiguas como duplicadas no evita que un recién llegado vuelva a hacer una pregunta similar si no ve referencias a la pregunta canónica. ¿No sería útil tener una sección "Canonical questions" en la página principal, igual que existe la de "Featured on meta"? Ahí podríamos meter esta, al igual que otras preguntas canónicas sobre otros temas que también sean recursivos. No sé, podría haber una pregunta canónica sobre el uso de "la", "le" y "lo", que también suele generar muchas dudas. Y ya puestos, otra sobre tipos de oraciones subordinadas.

Comment: @fedorqui o puede que sea tan sencillo como crear un _tag_ "canon" que se use sólo en este tipo de preguntas que sean canónicas, de uso restringido a moderadores y que se aplique sólo a preguntas _community wiki_ que traten un tema amplio pero recurrente.

Comment: Los sitios Meta tienen la sección "Frequently asked" (mira [meta.so], [meta.se] por ejemplo) y parece que están relacionadas con la etiqueta [faq]. Se podría crear una publicación del tipo "Cannonical questions" que las tuviera, pero veo dos pegas: 1) no sé si se puede enseñar en el sitio principal y 2) sería un enlace a un lugar donde estarían listadas todas, por lo que la información se difumina y es más difícil de ver por parte de los usuarios. No sé si esto puede corregirse, a ver si saco tiempo para preguntarlo en [meta.se].

Comment: Dicho lo cual, la clave de las preguntas canónicas es que tengan títulos lo suficientemente buenos como para que la gente los encuentre fácilmente. Especialmente cuando vayan a preguntar, pues el buscador que salta al escribir un título es el mejor que tiene este sitio. Además, es bueno que la gente sepa de las preguntas canónicas, para que colaboren indicándolo a los nuevos usuarios. A todo esto: me gusta el debate, esto está tomando forma :)

Comment: Nótese que angus ha publicado una interesante respuesta por aquí.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo acabo de descubrir una publicación interesante en [sf] que podría servirnos de modelo: [What are the canonical answers we've discovered over the years?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/1986/200076). Y cada pregunta que es de este tipo tiene un encabezado que lo indica: Véase [un ejemplo](http://serverfault.com/q/357108/200076).

Comment: @fedorqui la verdad es que parece una buena solución, y lo puede hacer cualquiera. Lo curioso es que, además de buscar preguntas canónicas entre las ya hechas, a veces hacen lo que decíamos de hacer preguntas hechas a propósito para que sean canónicas, y se responden por la comunidad o por el mismo que pregunta. Esto es básicamente hacer una sección de documentación como en SO pero con las propias preguntas. Lo importante es hacer en meta una lista de preguntas canónicas para que cualquiera pueda acceder a dicha lista.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Empecemos :) [¿Qué preguntas canónicas tenemos? What are the canonical answers we've discovered over the years?](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674). De momento, copié el formato de ese otro sitio (¡y el texto!) y traduje al castellano.

Comment: Recupero el tema: finalmente añadiste la pregunta canónica [What are the differences between “ser” and “estar”? When to use each? // ¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre “ser” y “estar”? ¿Cuándo se usa cada uno?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19836/1674). Si quieres, edita tu respuesta referenciándola para así poder marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Y lo mismo en [Respuesta detallada acerca de ser y estar](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2450/1674) que descubrí ahora y a la cual marco esta como duplicada.

Answer (score 1):

En principio no estoy de acuerdo. Este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, no una obra de referencia. Si alguien hace una pregunta y ya hay una respuesta que la responda perfectamente, está bien marcarla como duplicada. Pero si no, es mejor contestarla directamente, aunque se repita información que ya está en otras respuestas, porque, justamente, la característica de este sitio son las respuestas personalizadas a dudas o problemas concretos.

Si se crean respuestas “canónicas” aparecen las ganas de usarlas. Ahora, uno marca una pregunta como duplicada si de casualidad se acuerda de otra igual, o si la ve en los enlaces de la derecha. Con respuestas “canónicas” se empieza a buscar activamente a ver en cuál de ellas la puedo hacer encajar, tal vez forzándola un poquito... y el usuario se queda con una respuesta genérica que puede o no solventar su duda particular.

(Esto último agravado, sin ofender, por la falta de criterio que a veces tienen, por desconocimiento del idioma, nuestros moderadores extranjeros. No me extrañaría que la cosa terminara con uno de ellos viendo nada más el tag `ser y estar` y marcando automáticamente la pregunta como duplicada de la canónica sobre ser y estar...)

Para terminar, y como contrapeso a toda esta montaña de negatividad, la idea de preparar unas buenas preguntas y respuestas, bien tituladas, para que le aparezcan al usuario al buscar o al querer hacer una pregunta, me parece muy buena. Pero no marcarlas como “canónicas” ni nada de eso.

Comment: Pues creo que tu punto tiene mucho de útil. Antes de nada, yo sí creo que las respuestas canónicas a veces son necesarias. Me remito a un ejemplo: hace poco publiqué [esta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38972736/1983854) en [so] porque me daba cuenta que cosas muy parecidas se iban preguntando constantemente, pero no de forma lo suficientemente clara y genérica como para que una pudiera sobresalir como canónica "natural". Así que hice una "artificial" y, de momento, está siendo útil.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, tal vez una pregunta canónica sobre _ser y estar_ sería demasiado larga como para caber en un formato amigable para el sitio. Lo que podría plantearse es la subdivisión en casos típicos de confusión y o bien promover una pregunta canónica o bien escribirla cuidadosamente desde cero.

Comment: Comparto el hecho de que este sitio sea de preguntas y respuestas, no una obra de referencia. Ahora bien, para hacernos "respetar", afianzando los usuarios, debemos hacer que a) las personas que contestan sientan que es interesante lo que hacen y, por ende, no repetitivo b) las personas que preguntan sientan que no vale con venir, lanzar su duda e irse con la respuesta, sino que es una comunidad donde antes conviene investigar.

Comment: @fedorqui estaba pensando que, tal vez, donde mejor encajaría la pregunta canónica de ser/estar sea si Spanish Language tuviera una sección de documentación, como la recientemente estrenada en SO. Esa sección si está pensada para volcar conocimientos a espuertas, y desde luego si esa sección existiera aquí un apartado donde volcar todo lo referente a ser/estar sería idóneo.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo totalmente de acuerdo. Esto está en mente de la comunidad, pero veo que de momento no hay planes: [Allow Documentation in other Stack Exchange communities](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281689/209901). ¡Ojalá lo tengamos en algún momento!